# How to mock abstract method of an abstract class?

Tags: java, jmockit

I have a below method in which I am using this line `ProcBOF.getInstance().find` to get some data.

```
  private static Map<Long, Long> getAll(Map<Long, Event> holder) throws FinderException {
    Map<Long, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
    if (holder.isEmpty()) {
      return map;
    }
    Set<Long> items = holder.keySet();
    long[] itemIds = Longs.toArray(items);
    List<TeraBo> teraBos = TBOF.getInstance().findItemIdsIn(itemIds);
    for (TeraBo tBo : teraBos) {
      ProcessBo bo = ProcBOF.getInstance().find(tBo, holder.get(tBo.getItem().getId()).getDataId(), ReadSet.FULL, null);
      bo.getVar();
      map.put(tBo.getItem().getId(), bo.getVar());
    }
    return map;
  }
```

Now I want to mock the `find` method of `ProcBOF` class so that it can return some dummy `ProcessBo` object from which we can call `getVar()` method but the issue is `ProcBOF` is an abstract class and `find` is an abstract method so I am not able to understand how to mock this abstract method of abstract class.

```
public interface ProcessBo extends BOI {
    //...
}

public abstract class ProcBOF extends BaseBof {
    //...
    public abstract ProcessBo find(TeraBo saleBo, long dataId, ReadSet readSet, Filter filter) throws FinderException;
}
```

Comment: Refactor your code to eliminate the hidden dependencies and it will be both easier to work with and easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

You're implementation it's a little weird, so I'm not sure If I was able to reproduce it corretly (a getInstance() method on an abstract class is weird).

But, I think that with something like this it should work:

```
import mockit.Expectations;
import mockit.Mocked;
import mockit.Tested;
import mockit.integration.junit4.JMockit;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class Test {

    // Constants -----------------------------------------------------

    // Attributes ----------------------------------------------------

    /**Tested class*/
    @Tested
    private Foo foo;

    /**Mocked so that all instances are a mock*/
    @Mocked
    private ProcBOF procBOF;

    /**Mocked so that all instances are a mock*/
    @Mocked
    private ProcessBo processBo;

    // Constructors --------------------------------------------------

    // Static --------------------------------------------------------

    // Public --------------------------------------------------------

    @org.junit.Test
    public void name() throws Exception {
        // GIVEN
        new Expectations() {{
            // we mock the getInstance method and return always the mocked instance
            ProcBOF.getInstance();
            result = procBOF;

            // we mock the find method and return the mocked process Bo
            procBOF.find((TeraBo) any, 2L, ReadSet.FULL, null);
            result = processBo;

            // we also mock the getVar method
            processBo.getVar();
            result = "foo";
        }};

        // test data
        Map<Long, Event> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1L, new Event());

        // WHEN
        // call the getAll method
        Map<Long, Object> ret = foo.getAll(map);

        // THEN
        // we get the mocked value
        assertThat(ret.get(1L), is("foo"));
    }

    // Package protected ---------------------------------------------

    // Protected -----------------------------------------------------

    // Private -------------------------------------------------------

    // Inner classes -------------------------------------------------

}
```